# How to use a token alternative to GITHUB_TOKEN for a Github action?

Tags: github, token, github-actions, secret-key

I'm trying to add a Github Actions workflow to a repository. This action is from a third party and I'm not sure how much I can trust it so I'd prefer to use a dedicated `secret` instead of using the standard `GITHUB_TOKEN`. Is this a good practice?

I'm trying to do something like:

```yaml
name: 'coverage'
on:
    pull_request:
        branches:
            - master
            - main  
jobs:
    coverage:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        if: "!contains(github.event.head_commit.message, '[skip ci]')"
        steps:
            - uses: actions/checkout@v1
            - uses: unreliable/action@v1
              with:
                    github-token: ${{ secrets.NEW_SECRET_TOKEN }}
```

where `secrets.NEW_SECRET_TOKEN` is a repo secret.

But what I get is a 401 error, bad credentials. How can I use NEW_SECRET_TOKEN for my new action?

Answer (score 1):

You can add them in repo settings -> Secrets.

Comment: My  bad, I didn't specify that I've actually already created the new token as a repo secret. I've updated my question.

Comment: just use them like in line 44 here https://github.com/TheCommonCold/covid-info-service/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml

Comment: How would that be possible with a github action?

Comment: what I linked is literally a github action declaration